# CloudFormation - Using - >- expression with !Sub

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Can I use - >- with !Sub?

```
Properties:
   DashboardBody: !Sub
    - >-
      '{
             ... too long json ...
      '}
    - {something else}
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will work. Here is an example:

```
Resources:

  MyDashBoard:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Dashboard
    Properties: 
        DashboardBody: 
          !Sub
            - >-
              {
                 "widgets": [
                    {
                      "type": "metric",
                      "width": 12,
                      "height": 6,
                      "properties": {
                          "metrics": [
                              ["AWS/EC2","CPUUtilization","AutoScalingGroupName","<your-asg-name>"]
                          ],
                          "region": "${AWS::Region}",
                          "period": 60,
                          "title": "${title}"
                      }
                   }
                ]
              }
            - title: "my-dasboard-title"
        DashboardName: my-dashboard-name
```